# GCM (Google cloud messaging) - can I register multiple devices with same register id?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android application.

I want to **register one device** with GCM and obtain the **RegistrationID**. I would like to ask if I am going to use the second device with the same app, is it possible to somehow use the **RegistrationID obtained on the first device** to this **second device**?

Answer (score 2):

No. Moreover, you should not need to. You can use [user notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html) to be able to send a single message from the server to all instances of your app across all the user's devices.

Answer (score 2):

No. What you need is notification_key and notification_key_name. The registration_id is generated per application on device - the same app on a different device or a different app on the same device would generate a different key. 
With notification_key, you can map up to 10 registration_ids to a single user (a single key)

Comment: By notification_key you mean API key? Also, what do you mean by: you can map up to 10 registration_ids to a single user ?

Comment: @justME npace refers to [user notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html), a relatively new feature. It has nothing to do with the API key.

Comment: I suggest that you read through the Getting Started and Architectural Overview sections of the GCM tutorial on the Android developers website. It's quite a complex subject, but reading a big chunk of the documentation should help.

Answer (score 0):

Create database and save all RegistrationID, then in php file, replace `array("RegistrationID")` to `array("RegistrationID database1","RegistrationID database2",....);`